# list iterators incompatible with erasing

Tags: c++, list, debugging

Here's my code:

```
std::list<User>::iterator it;
    while (it != allUsers.end())
    {
        if (it->getId() == userId)
        {
            allUsers.remove(*it);
            return *it;
        }
        else
        {
            it++;
        }
    }
```

The error I get : list iterators incompatible with erasing 
Why?

Comment: The iterator is invalid after `remove`. You cannot access it.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact message.

Comment: Removing a value from a list uses erases the removed elements, which invalidates iterators that refer to elements of that list.   So `allUsers.remove(*it)` invalidates `it`.   Dereferencing it (as in `return *it`)` then causes undefined behaviour.  Your compiler is telling you that (roughly speaking).

Comment: Show the full function and the `User` class. Make a [mcve]. `it` is default constructed and will not automatically start at `allUsers.begin()`.

Comment: @Hee hee The iterator  std::list<User>::iterator it; is not initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase), not `remove()` to remove an element from a list using an iterator:

```
while (it != allUsers.end()) {
    if (it->getId() == userId) {
        auto oldvalue = *it;
        allUsers.erase(it);
        return oldvalue;
    }
    it++;
}
```